# Hide links to pages that dont have any content

Tags: pages, links

Its that possible?Than when something is added to page in admin panel, page link to that page appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need to implode(',',$excluded_pages) for things to work,

```
$excluded_pages = array();
$all_pages = get_pages();
foreach ( $all_pages as $the_page ) {
    if ( '' == $the_page->post_content ) {
        $excluded_pages[] = $the_page->ID;
    }
}
wp_list_pages( array(
    'exclude' => implode(',',$excluded_pages)
) );
```

**EDIT**

Comment: clever,tnx.But I igot complicated menu structure.Any idea how to implement this on my code?
take a look:
<li><a><?php _e('Локална самоуправа'); ?></a>
<ul><?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&sort_column=menu_order&include=265,267,269'); ?>
<li><a><?php _e('Скупштина Општине'); ?></a>
<ul><?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&sort_column=menu_order&include=536,551,556,558,564,566,568'); ?></ul>
</li>
and so on ...

Comment: See edited answer.